# Notice: Trying to get property 'currentdate' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\clearance.php

Tags: php, mysql

Here's the code
I'm trying to echo the data from the clearance form table if the $today date matches with the  $expirydate from the clearance table

```php
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$expirydate = $row->currentdate; //from database

$today_time = strtotime($today);
$expire_time = strtotime($expirydate);

if ($expire_time < $today_time) {
    echo '(body....) ';
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: Also, please do not use irrelevant tags - your question does not contain any code related to MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arrow `->` is also called the **object operator** and is used to access *properties* or *non-static methods* on an object of a class.

---

You should **debug** your code to check the **type** of `$row` because it obviously is **not an object** that has an property `currentdate`. Because of this the error you got was thrown.

---

As a bonus tip you should also check out the [null-safe operator](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/nullsafe_operator) which checks for `null`

Quote from https://wiki.php.net/rfc/nullsafe_operator:

> When the left hand side of the operator evaluates to null the
> execution of the entire chain will stop and evalute to null. When it
> is not null it will behave exactly like the normal -> operator.